# Access denied to new window which was created from https page in ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, security

I'm trying to create a new window in Internet Explorer 9 from a page with HTTPS connection. I want to paste the new HTML contents from an AJAX callback to the popup like this:

```
var popup = window.top.open("about:blank", "popup", "height=700,width=700");
```

All other browsers work with the new window correctly, but in IE9 I get *Access denied* and can't work with the new window. I think it is because of some specific security reason, but I can't fix this problem.

I didn't use other domains or something else. Seems that, because of `about:blank` as the URL, IE doesn't trust the new window and doesn't want to grant access to it from the originating HTTPS page.